# How to get access to Microsoft.SharePoint in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint

I was asked to look into a small GUI based C# sharepoint project.  The thing is, the reference to Microsoft.SharePoint.dll is missing on my machine.  Now I looked inside Windows Explorer > Common Files > Microsoft Shared > Web Server Extensions > (two folders are present here 15 and 16) > ISAPI.  The dll should be inside this folder but it isn't.  I see Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll but the classes inside the C# project directly reference SharePoint.dll  I am unable to debug the code.  I need some help on this.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only reference Microsoft.SharePoint.dll if you run locally on the server.

If you want to remotely access to SharePoint, you have to use one the client technology able to connect to SharePoint.

This can be:

- CSOM (available as [nuget packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=csom), depending on the target version of SharePoint)
- REST API, which does not require any 3rd party library
- Old school asmx WebService

Depending on your needs, the 1st is often the easiest.

Comment: Wonderful!  Thanks Steve :D